# How to export Next.js static app for use in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, next.js

### <s>How can I inline `_next/*` files in `out/index.html`?</s>

### How can I whitelist `_next/` directory in `manifest.json`?

---

I followed the instructions for [exporting a static app](https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/static-html-export/setup), and used a simple manifest.

```
** manifest.json **
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "E1-static-export",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Demo static export with inline / CSP hashes",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "out/index.html"
  }
}
```

1. `yarn build && yarn export` from `/E1-static-export`
2. load unpacked extension in `chrome://extensions`
3. right click browser icon Inspect Popup

[Filed an issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7315) because I've spend ~5 hours researching!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; I'm working on a better solution, but I discovered that Chrome doesn't follow underscores in the directory path.

My error had nothing to do with CSP, I merely had to rename `_next` to `Znext` and rename all occurrences within that directory. Following the static export tutorial, I ended up with a navigable "default_popup" palette with flawless client-side routing and my required package (crypto).

No need for `"web_accessible_resources"` or `"content_security_policy"` changes.

Comment: hey, could you maybe share a repo of the base structure?

Comment: @Zarazas I think I just used the link for next.js static app in the question; not sure if anything is missing aside from that manifest